# null reference when invoking startActivityForResult

Tags: java

Whenever the startActivityForResult method is invoked within the onCreate, I get the following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent
> com.wifi.service.displayexample.DisplayService.sendIntent()' on a null
> object reference at
> com.wifi.service.displayexample.DisplayActivity.onCreate(DisplayActivity.java:75)

DisplayActivity.java

```
DisplayService displayService = DisplayService.Companion.getINSTANCE();

    //No streaming/recording start service
    if (displayService == null) {
      Log.d("TAG", "startService");
      startService(new Intent(this, DisplayService.class));
    }

    startActivityForResult(displayService.sendIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_STREAM);
```

DisplayService.kt

```
fun sendIntent(): Intent? {
    return displayBase?.sendIntent()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement checks whether the displayService object is null or not. Then right after it, you're invoking the sendIntent method on an object that might be null.

You definitely want to place that startActivityForResult invocation in an else branch to make sure that displayService is not null.

```
    //No streaming/recording start service
    if (displayService == null) {
       Log.d("TAG", "startService");
       startService(new Intent(this, DisplayService.class));
    } else {
       startActivityForResult(displayService.sendIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_STREAM);
    }
```